# Is there a way to find a character's index(or indexes if multiple) with logn time complexity?

Tags: algorithm

basically i am trying to find all the indexes of a char in a string using logn time complexity(space complexity is not important) and also we can sort the string by the char value of each char if that could potentially help (we wont count the time complexity of the sorting algorithm used)

i think it has something to do with binary search so my main thought is to first sort the string(keeping the initial indexes somewhere )and then perform binary search to find the indexes of  each element

Comment: You want the indices _before_ or _after_ sorting? Not including the sorting is sort of cheating, since that has _higher_ complexity than a simple linear search. Your suggestion should work, though. Have you tried it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: the problem i am at now is if there is more than one occurrence of a char in my string and how to handle it without messing up the time complexity

Comment: You could also create a hash-map/dictionary, mapping each char to a list of all positions the char occurs at. That's O(n) for creating the dict and O(1) for finding the indices, as opposed to O(nlogn) for sorting and then O(logn) for binary searching the first and last index, and simpler to implement, too.

Comment: Hashmap is a great idea but i cant take O(n) for creating it my problem is a part of a bigger problem which i desire to get an O(nlogn) complexity for that is the reason i ignore the sorting time complexity and i need to do the search for n arguments so having O(n) as the time complexity for the search algorithm creates an O(n^2) time complexity which is not optimal

Comment: Why can you "ignore" the O(nlogn) for sorting, but not the O(n) for creating the hash map? Maybe you should sketch the "bigger problem" for some context.